# understanding and applying pytorch datasets

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying understand pytorch datasets but i can't. I'm read a lot of code about it and i can't understand how to use different type of inputs and output. I've tried inputs that are the same type. it works normally but i can't try different types of inputs because i don't know how. If i have a dataset like this.

Inputs
|
|--- RGB-Image
|--- Depth-Image
|--- Labels
Output
|
|--- Mesh

How can i give all of them to ai? or can i give them?

the codes I'm trying to read are: [pixel2mesh](https://github.com/Tong-ZHAO/Pixel2Mesh-Pytorch), [3dmm-fitting](https://github.com/ascust/3DMM-Fitting-Pytorch), [flame](https://github.com/soubhiksanyal/FLAME_PyTorch)

I can't see any opened image or giving image to torch. Maybe i am missing anything. I think this codes are extreme but i can't find any non-theoretical tutorial or documents.

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please provide what you've tried so far.

Comment: I don't try anything because i can't understand how. I want any non-theoretical tutorial (video or doc) or any narration

Comment: Ok, in this case please read through this [tutorial page](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html) which will get you started writing custom datasets for PyTorch.